# Select MKMarkerAnnotationView with custom callout after adding annotation

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios11

I have an MKMapView on which I would like to add annotations on a long press gesture. After adding the annotation, I would like to select the annotation view. Quite a simple request I assumed.

The problem is that I am using the new MKMarkerAnnotationView with a custom rightCalloutAccessoryView and a custom detailCalloutAccessoryView. It is not very well documented yet, but the [WWDC 2017 Session 237](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/) states that the callout will be displayed when there is more than a title/subtitle.

Unfortunately, this is not the case for me. When I programmatically (and manually) select the annotation, I get a weird double selected state where I can see the callout AND the marker:

[image: selected state]

Here is the annotation view code:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
protocol TemporaryUserAnnotationViewDelegate: class {
    func temporaryUserAnnotationViewDidTapOk(title: String?, userAnnotationView: TemporaryUserAnnotationView)
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class TemporaryUserAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    weak var delegate: TemporaryUserAnnotationViewDelegate?
    var textField: UITextField!

    init(annotation: TemporaryUserAnnotation) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: TemporaryUserAnnotationMarkerAnnotationView.reuseIdentifier)
        markerTintColor = .lbc_blue
        canShowCallout = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure(annotation: TemporaryUserAnnotation) {
        let detailView = UIView()
        detailView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.placeholder = "Titre"
        detailView.addSubview(textField)
        detailView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21).isActive = true
        detailView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21).isActive = true
        textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailView

        let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 70)))
        rightView.backgroundColor = .lbc_blue
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 40)))
        button.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapRightCalloutAccessoryViewButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        rightView.addSubview(button)
        rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightView
    }

    @objc func tapRightCalloutAccessoryViewButton() {
        delegate?.temporaryUserAnnotationViewDidTapOk(title: textField.text, userAnnotationView: self)
    }
}
```

and here is the controller code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    print(#function)
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        switch annotation {
        case let temporarayUserAnnotation as TemporaryUserAnnotation:
            if let view = mapView.dequeue() as? TemporaryUserAnnotationView {
                view.annotation = annotation
                return view
            } else {
                let view = TemporaryUserAnnotationView(annotation: temporarayUserAnnotation)
                view.delegate = self
                view.configure(annotation: temporarayUserAnnotation)
                return view
            }
        default:
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        let identifier = "marker"
        if let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
            view.annotation = annotation
            return view
        } else {
            return MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }
    }
}
```

I simply add annotations this way:

```
func addUserAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let annotation = TemporaryUserAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
}
```

I also tried to implement the `mapView(_:didAdd:)` method but the result is even worse with the marker view in front of the callout.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just encountered a similar problem because I had a `UITapGestureRecognizer` of my own competing with `MKMapView`'s selection gesture recognizer. I created and selected the annotation on the tap event, but because both gesture recognizers were firing, and theirs was firing last, it was deselecting immediately.

My solution was to implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and become the delegate of my gesture recognizer, and implement the following:

```
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the following workaround: when you add your annotation, wait a second before programmatically selecting it:

```
func addUserAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let annotation = TemporaryUserAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I still think this should not be necessary, so if you have a better solution, feel free to post it here!